# Elasticsearch Search Query using python subprocess: Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: python, elasticsearch, curl, elasticsearch-api

I am trying to run a curl command using the [run command in the subprocess module](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-subprocess-to-run-external-programs-in-python-3) in python. But it is failing.
However, the curl command for my elasticsearch search query API is working fine-

```
curl -k XGET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: ApiKey Q2txZ2FvSUJ6Nlcwa3pjbnh0NUM6enBidjdNLTdRQVNhc0tuTEk5UEZmZw==" 'https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200/_search?index=.fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7&size=20&pretty' -d '{"query": {"match": {"_id": "c8a537a9-7f98-489b-8f8b-de2450c67ce6"}},"fields" : ["_id", "_index"]}'
```

This is the code that I am trying to run-

```
import json
from builtins import int
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List, Dict
from subprocess import PIPE, run

def elasticsearch_search_query(host: str, 
                               port: int, 
                               api_key: str, 
                               path: str, 
                               query: dict,
                               index: str,
                               size: int,
                               fields: List):

    es_path = host + ":" + str(port) + path +"?index="+index+"&"+str(size)+"&pretty"
    es_header = "Authorization: ApiKey" + " " + api_key
    es_dict = {"query": query, "fields": fields}
    es_json = json.dumps(es_dict)
    es_replaced = " "+"'"+ es_json.replace("'", "\"")+"'"

    result = run(["curl", "-k", "-XGET", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-H",
                  es_header,
                  es_path,
                  "-d",
                  es_replaced]
                 # ,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False
                )
    print(es_path, es_header, es_replaced)
    print(result.stdout)


elasticsearch_search_query(host="https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200/_search", api_key="Q2txZ2FvSUJ6Nlcwa3pjbnh0NUM6enBidjdNLTdRQVNhc0tuTEk5UEZmZw==",
                           port=9200, size=5, query={"match": {"_id": "c8a537a9-7f98-489b-8f8b-de2450c67ce6"}}, fields=["_id", "_index"], path="/_search",index=".fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7")
```

Here is the error-

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "request [/_search:9200/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [5]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/_search:9200/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [5]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200/_search:9200/_search?index=.fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7&5&pretty Authorization: ApiKey Q2txZ2FvSUJ6Nlcwa3pjbnh0NUM6enBidjdNLTdRQVNhc0tuTEk5UEZmZw== '{"query": {"match": {"_id": "c8a537a9-7f98-489b-8f8b-de2450c67ce6"}}, "fields": ["_id", "_index"]}'
None

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   350  100   350    0     0  10294      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10294
curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 12:
'{"query": {"match": {"_id": "c8a537a9-7f98-489b-8f8b-de2450c67ce6"}}, "fields": ["_id", "_index"]}'
```

**UPDATE**

Output of repr(result):

```
CompletedProcess(args=['curl', '-k', '-XGET', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json', '-H', 'Authorization: ApiKey Q2txZ2FvSUJ6Nlcwa3pjbnh0NUM6enBidjdNLTdRQVNhc0tuTEk5UEZmZw==', 'https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200:9200/_search?index=.fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7&size=5&pretty', '-d', '{"query": {"match": {"_id": "c8a537a9-7f98-489b-8f8b-de2450c67ce6"}}, "fields": ["_id", "_index"]}'], returncode=3)
```

Comment: `es_replaced` is inherently broken. You're adding single quotes -- that's _shell quotes_ -- to your data; but when you run a shell command the shell removes those quotes before it hands anything off to `curl`; they are not, and should not be, part of your data.

Comment: So when there's no shell, you shouldn't be adding shell quotes. Take the `'`s out, and leave the double quotes exactly the way `json.dumps()` made them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I removed the es_replaced variable and I am using es_json as it is. After which I am getting this error- curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: Please log the `repr()` of the array you're feeding to `run()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is the output of repr(result)-  CompletedProcess(args=['curl', '-k', '-XGET', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json', '-H', 'Authorization: ApiKey Q2txZ2FvSUJ6Nlcwa3pjbnh0NUM6enBidjdNLTdRQVNhc0tuTEk5UEZmZw==', 'https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200:9200/_search?index=.fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7&size=5&pretty', '-d', '{"query": {"match": {"_id": "c8a537a9-7f98-489b-8f8b-de2450c67ce6"}}, "fields": ["_id", "_index"]}'], returncode=3)

Comment: Can you put that in backticks so Stack Overflow doesn't munge it? I assume there was really a `https://` in the URL, but it's not shown above. Or just edit it into the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Done, please check the UPDATE part in the question. Also, as an update, I checked the URL I had specified the port number twice. Thank you so much! It got resolved.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! That part of the problem is probably off-topic here ("caused by a typo"). If you want to keep the question around, maybe edit to focus in on a different technical issue, like one of the ones we previously solved  (be it the missing `size=` or the extra quoting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error was

> contains unrecognized parameter: [5]

The problem is not in the query but in the way you construct `es_path`. Instead of

```
&"+str(size)+
```

it should be

```
&size="+str(size)+
```

**UPDATE:**

Also from what I see your URL now looks like this

```
https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200:9200/_search?index=.fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7&size=5&pretty
```

and it's wrong for the following reasons:

- the port is specified twice
- the index is not at the right location

First, `host` should just be this (i.e. without port and path)

```
host="https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
```

Then you can build the URL like this instead:

```
es_path = host + ":" + str(port) + "/" + index + path +"?size="+str(size)+"&pretty"
```

i.e. it should look like this instead:

```
https://internal-a02c1b85dade940ef871b0b6d1e65191-1270244841.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9200/.fleet-enrollment-api-keys-7/_search?size=5&pretty
```

Comment: The query _is_ also wrong, insofar as the OP is shell-quoting data that should be passed literally.

Comment: The first error shown is about the query string having an unknown parameter. But you're probably right that maybe once the query string is corrected, the next issue will be the query itself as hinted by the curl error

Comment: Thanks, the issue was resolved. But now I am getting this error- curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: I also removed the single quotes in es_replaced

Comment: I think `es_path` must also be wrapped within quotes because of the `&` sign

Comment: @Val, quotes are needed to protect `&` **from the shell**, but the OP is using `subprocess.run()` without `shell=True`, so there is no shell to protect from.

Comment: @Val, moreover, when quotes are used as shell syntax, the shell removes them before calling the program that it starts, so if you added extra quotes to the argv, curl wouldn't know what to do with them.

Comment: Yep got it @Val! Thank you for updating the answer